# Parse JSON array of arrays

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Php array of arrays  which is json encoded as

```
 [{"TASK_ID":"79","USER_ID":"cool12",
   "LATITUDE":"32.702550412612524",
   "LONGITUDE":"74.85893413424492",
   "STARTED_ON":"2016-06-07 14:57:05",
   "STOPED_ON":"2016-06-07 14:57:05",
   "DEVICE_ID":null,"DEVICE_NAME":null,
   "DEVICE_TYPE":null,"PATH_ENDED":"0"},  
   {"TASK_ID":"80",
    "USER_ID":"cool12", 
   "LATITUDE":"32.70255831226375",
  "LONGITUDE":"74.85894754529",
  "STARTED_ON":"2016-06-07 14:57:06",
  "STOPED_ON":"2016-06-07 14:57:06",
 "DEVICE_ID":null,
  "DEVICE_NAME":null,
  "DEVICE_TYPE":null,
 "PATH_ENDED”:”0”}]


var ar = <?php echo json_encode($resultArray) ?>;
```

gives this result

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 25 more… ]
```

How to parse this array to get the values

Comment: `JSON.parse`.                                                    .

Comment: You don't need to do anything, the result is an array literal so *ar* is an array of objects. Iterate over the array to get at the objects, e.g. `ar.forEach(function(obj){console.log(obj.TASK_ID)})`.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode()` is a function that creates a `JSON` string out of a PHP array.

> Important thing to note here is `PHP array` is somewhat similar to
>   `Javascript Object` containing `key` and `value` pairs.

Hence, after you get your variable `ar` in javascript all you have to do is `JSON.parse(ar)`, and then walk through the variable by any of the following loops (or any other custom function) :

- `forEach`
- `for in` loop
- `for of` loop